# Error cleaning or building project on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I receive this message when I clean or build my project on android studio

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
>   Unable to delete directory: C:\bt\CatedralVerano\app\build\outputs\apk

I search on severals post and nothing work

I tried to delete the directory and I receive an error message with this code

> Error 0x80070570
>   The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Solutions?

Comment: Close your android studio and delete files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go into task manager and kill any running java or jvm running in the background then try clean again. Should work.